# How to correctly create a batch normalization layer for a convolutional layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was looking at the [official batch normalization layer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100) (BN) in TensorFlow however it didn't really explain how to use it for a convolutional layer. Does someone know how to do this? In particular its important that it applies and learns **the same parameters per feature map** (rather than per activation). In other order that it applies and learn BN per filter.

In a specific toy example say that I want to do conv2d with BN on MNIST (2D data essentially). Thus one could do:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32]) # 5x5 filters with 32 filters
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1]) # MNIST image
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x_image, W_conv1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') #[?,24,24,1]
z = conv # [?,24,24,32]
z = BN(z) # [?,24,24,32], essentially only 32 different scales and shift parameters to learn, per filer application
a = tf.nn.relu(z) # [?,24,24,32]
```

Where `z = BN(z)` applies the BN to each feature created by each individual filter. In pseudocode:

```
x_patch = x[h:h+5,w:w+h,1] # patch to do convolution
z[h,w,f] = x_patch * W[:,:,f] = tf.matmul(x_patch, W[:,:,f]) # actual matrix multiplication for the convolution
```

we have a proper batch norm layer applied to it (in pseudocode omitting important details):

```
z[h,w,f] = BN(z[h,w,f]) = scale[f] * (z[h,w,f]  - mu / sigma) + shift[f]
```

i.e. for each filter `f` we apply BN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: the links I provide here affect the `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` module, and not the usual `tf.nn` (see comments and post below)**

I didn't test it, but the way TF expects you to use it seems to be documented in the `convolution2d` [docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L279):

```
def convolution2d(inputs,
              num_outputs,
              kernel_size,
              stride=1,
              padding='SAME',
              activation_fn=nn.relu,
              normalizer_fn=None,
              normalizer_params=None,
              weights_initializer=initializers.xavier_initializer(),
              weights_regularizer=None,
              biases_initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer,
              biases_regularizer=None,
              reuse=None,
              variables_collections=None,
              outputs_collections=None,
              trainable=True,
              scope=None):
  """Adds a 2D convolution followed by an optional batch_norm layer.
  `convolution2d` creates a variable called `weights`, representing the
  convolutional kernel, that is convolved with the `inputs` to produce a
  `Tensor` of activations. If a `normalizer_fn` is provided (such as
  `batch_norm`), it is then applied. Otherwise, if `normalizer_fn` is
  None and a `biases_initializer` is provided then a `biases` variable would be
  created and added the activations.
```

Following this suggestion, you should add `normalizer_fn='batch_norm'` as a parameter to your conv2d method call.

Regarding the feature map vs. activation question, my guess is that TF would add the normalization layer as a new "node" on the top of the conv2d one when building the graph, and that both of them would modify the same weights variable (in your case, the W_conv1 object). I wouldn't describe anyway the task of the norm layer as "learning", but I'm not quite sure if I understood your point (maybe I can try to help further if you elaborate on that)

**EDIT**:
Taking a closer look to the body of the function confirms my guess, and also explains how the `normalized_params` parameter is used. Reading from [line 354](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L354):

```
outputs = nn.conv2d(inputs, weights, [1, stride_h, stride_w, 1],
padding=padding)
if normalizer_fn:
  normalizer_params = normalizer_params or {}
  outputs = normalizer_fn(outputs, **normalizer_params)
else:
  ...etc...
```

we see that the `outputs` variable, holding the respective output of each layer, is sequentially overwritten. So, if a `normalizer_fn` is given when building the graph, the output of `nn.conv2d` is going to be overwritten with the extra layer `normalizer_fn`. Here is where the `**normalizer_params`  come to play, passed as a [kwarg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) iterable to the given `normalizer_fn`. You can find the default parameters to `batch_norm` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100), so passing a dictionary to normalizer_params with the ones that you wish to change should do the trick, something like this:

```
normalizer_params = {"epsilon" : 0.314592, "center" : False}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you know what `normalizer_params` does?

Comment: yes that was helpful thnx! Btw, have you managed to have a running example? I've been having some issue with it.

Comment: unfortunately not... I realized that I was using the `tf.nn.conv2d` function, which is not the same as the described under 'contrib/layers... etc (the file you provided)'. Then I grepped, and dived into the nn.py and nn_ops.py files in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/python/ops but got totally lost because of some aliasing system involving `local_response_normalization` or something like that...  Maybe I'll give it a try in the future, but I would try first to directly use the tf.contrib.layers.whateverElse.conv2d function

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following example works for me:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf


normalizer_fn = None
normalizer_fn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm

D = 5
kernel_height = 1
kernel_width = 3
F = 4
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1,D,1], name='x-input') #[M, 1, D, 1]
conv = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs=x,
    num_outputs=F, # 4
    kernel_size=[kernel_height, kernel_width], # [1,3]
    stride=[1,1],
    padding='VALID',
    rate=1,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    normalizer_fn=normalizer_fn,
    normalizer_params=None,
    weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(dtype=tf.float32),
    biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer,
    trainable=True,
    scope='cnn'
)

# syntheitc data
M = 2
X_data = np.array( [np.arange(0,5),np.arange(5,10)] )
print(X_data)
X_data = X_data.reshape(M,1,D,1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
    print( sess.run(fetches=conv, feed_dict={x:X_data}) )
```

Console output:

```
$ python single_convolution.py
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]
[[[[ 1.33058071  1.33073258  1.30027914  0.        ]
   [ 0.95041472  0.95052338  0.92877126  0.        ]
   [ 0.57024884  0.57031405  0.55726254  0.        ]]]


 [[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.56916821]
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.94861376]
   [ 0.          0.          0.          1.32805932]]]]
```